# Как изменять свойства объекта state с сохранением предыдущий значений

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

Суть: Есть 4 поля куда вводятся значения, необходимо записать эти значения.

Проблема: При каждом вызове обработчика события происходит перезапись всего объекта с изменением значения одного свойства, остальные значения свойств равны 0, не сохраняются значения введенные в другие поля.

```
class BlockInput extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: {
            width: 0,
            length: 0,
            thickness: 0,
            height: 0
        }
    }
    this.clickChange = this.clickChange.bind(this);
    }

    clickChange(event){
        const keysState = Object.keys(this.state.data);
        keysState.map(item => {
            if (event.target.name === item) {
                this.setState(prevState=>({data: {...prevState.data, [item]: event.target.value}}));
            }
         })
         console.log(this.state.data)
    }
    render(){
        const {name, id, className} = this.props;
        return (
            <Input type="text" onChange={this.clickChange} name={id} autocomplete="off" placeholder="0 см" ></Input>
        )
    }
}
```

Ввожу в поле width консоль отвечает: width: '2', length: 0, thickness: 0, height: 0

После ввожу в поле length консоль отвечает: width: 0, length: '2', thickness: 0, height: 0

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить функцию обработчик вот так:

```
clickChange(event){
    if (this.state.data.hasOwnProperty(event.target.name)) {
        const upd = {};
        upd[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({data: { ...this.state.data, ...upd}})
    }
}
```

В такой конструкции spread оператор будет работать правильно и мержить значения.

Так же для события нажатия кнопки, орагнизовывать цикл map по всем ключам - скажем так, лишнее

Так же в рендере надо Input присваивать значение из state

```
render(){
    const {name, id, className} = this.props;
    return (
        <Input type="text" onChange={this.clickChange} name={id} autocomplete="off" placeholder="0 см" value={this.state.data[id]}></Input>
    )
}
```

Comment: Я прогонял по циклам, чтобы получить имена свойств item, в вашем коде, есть переменная item

Comment: Поправил переменную. У вас по коду получается что `event.target.name` должно соответствовать ключу в `this.state.data`

Comment: да, спасибо, намудрил, но код пока не запускается, ругается видимо на синтаксис в этом районе ...[event.target.name]: event.target.value

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","  при наведении на двоеточие

Comment: Подправил определение переменной

Comment: К сожалению та же картина, перезаписывает на нули другие свойства

Comment: Добавил в ответ изменения для `render()`

Comment: пока тоже самое)

Comment: в методе render() поставьте `console.log(this.state)` и посмотрите, state меняется или нет

Comment: тоже думал может внутри функции он не меняется ещё, по этому выносил в render консоль лог, так что не в этом соль

Comment: Всё, на англ версии спросил, забавная причина. Я же вызываю 4 раза этот компонент input, и для каждого input своё состояние, которое не может подтянуть состояние другого компонента input

Answer (score 0):

К какому выводу я пришел:
Нельзя изменить state компонента (в моем случае input), для всех экземпляров этого компонента, state устанавливается только для конкретного экземпляра.
Для установки значений всех экземпляров компонента в state, необходимо устанавливать state в компоненте-сборщике компонентов input, в котором вызываются все, в моем случае 4 компонента-input.

Код выглядит след образом:

```
class BlockInput extends Component {
    clickChange = (event) => {
        const arr = {}
        arr[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        this.props.valueNum(arr)
    }
render(){
    const {name, id, className} = this.props;
    return (
    <DivInput className={className}>
        <SpanText>{name}</SpanText>
        <Input type="text" onChange={this.clickChange} name={id} autoСomplete="off" placeholder="0 см"></Input>
    </DivInput>)
}}


export default class Corner extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            names: { width: 'Ширина',
                    length: 'Длина',
                    thickness: 'Толщина',
                    height: 'Высота'
            },
            values: {
                    width: 0,
                    length: 0,
                    thickness: 0,
                    height: 0
            }
        }
    }

    getValue = (id) => {
        return this.setState({values: { ...this.state.values, ...id}})
    }
render(){
    const {width, length, thickness, height} = this.state.names;
    return (
    <>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center transition" >
            <BlockInput id ={'width'} name={width} className={'inputWidth'} valueNum={this.getValue}></BlockInput>
            <BlockInput id ={'length'} name={length} className={'inputLength'} valueNum={this.getValue}></BlockInput>
            <BlockInput id ={'thickness'} name={thickness} className={'inputThickness'} valueNum={this.getValue}></BlockInput>
            <BlockInput id ={'height'} name={height} className={'inputHeight'} valueNum={this.getValue}></BlockInput>
            <YourSvg className="svg"></YourSvg>
        </div>
    </>
    )
}  
}
```

Нахожусь в стадии обучения, код рабочий, но далеко не идеальный